# How to find files bigger than 2gb Windows command line? (32 bit overflow prevents the well known method working)

Tags: windows, command-line, file-search, size

I am using the following well known solution to recursively find files greater than a specified value:

```
forfiles /S /M * /C "cmd /c if @fsize GEQ 2000000000 echo @path"
```

This perfectly works except if I try to use this command to find something bigger than 2^31. For example

```
forfiles /S /M * /C "cmd /c if @fsize GEQ 3000000000 echo @path"
```

has issues because it also returns files with size of 2310123265, not only files greater than 3000000000

My guess it is something about the 32 bit signed integer arithmetic.

**Question**

How can I search for files greater than say 3gb?

Comment: Do you need this to work on like Windows XP, or can one just post a PowerShell answer?

Comment: Many thx for your comment. Any solution which works on a 64 bit Windows system will do it. I think in 2021 if one expects Windows XP compatibility, then it must be mentioned explicitely in the OP. However, just for curiosity, I would like to know, how to overcome the 32 bit limitation on a system, which supports file sizes bigger than 2gb, but its shell comparision operator does not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PowerShell has no problems with large values:

```
gci -file -recurse | ? length -ge 3e9
gci -File -Recurse | where Length -ge 3000000000
Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse | where { $_.Length -ge 3000000000 }
```

To get just the paths, pipe the result through Format-Table, but be careful to [avoid truncation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49123225/49849):

```
... | ft FullName -auto
```

<sup>(that's one area where PowerShell *does* have problems)</sup>

- [Get-ChildItem](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-7.1) (alias: `gci`)
- [Where-Object](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object?view=powershell-7.1) (alias: `?`, `where`)
- [about_Comparison_Operators](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.1) (`{ -ge }`)
- [Format-Table](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/format-table?view=powershell-7.1) (alias: `ft`)